# Module compiled with Swift 4.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.50

Tags: swift, audiokit, swift4.1, xcode10, swift4.1.5

I'm using AudioKit 4.3 in XCode 10 but I'm running into this problem while building

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AudioKit doesn't officially support beta software, especially for pre-built binaries, so if you want to use Xcode 10, download the AudioKit source and build it yourself from the Frameworks/ folder run ./build_frameworks.sh

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-run `pod install` or update your library if it is available. And then clean your project `shift + command + k` until you cannot see error and then you build it.
If you use Carthage just run this command `carthage update --platform iOS`